# Should I choose MySQL or MongoDB for this design

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database

I'm struggling to choose between MySQL and MongoDB. I'm creating a rating/review system on my products and I should be able to calculate overall rating by calculating the average of ratings. my design is like this:

**table products_review**

- id
- productId (int)
- rating (int)
- comment (string)
- dateCreated (date)
- userId (int)

Assuming that I have a large (millions) dataset of products and in future large dataset of rating/reviews [for example something like Yelp], which database should I choose MongoDB or MySQL?

Comment: If you won't reach > 1000000 I'd go with the one you are more interested in. Both will have about the same performance. To get to see MongoDB's real power you'd need a few shards and multi threaded aggregation.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have about 30 million products but that doesn't mean I'm getting review on all of them. I think I'll go with mySQL

Comment: With mysql, you can still pre-aggregate the average rating for example. Good choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it realist that you will have milions of reviews, or you are just over exagerating?

In your case I would go for mySQL. What do you have there is close to a relational schema therefore I would go relational. If you think the data is too much, you can have a table for February reviews, another for March reviews and so on; you can also do the partitioning by product category or something else.

If you want to go mongoDB you do have to modify the schema and fully denormalize it. You must not be aware, but on mongoDB you do not have the join therefore, you will not be able to join that the products table, therefore you have to store the product name and description together with the rating (or don't you want to do something like a group by product name?). Hence, on mongoDB it would look something like this:

```
_id 
productId 
productName,
product description,
product category,
product
rating 
comment 
dateCreated 
userId 
username,
userGenger (male/female/unknow)
userAge
userRegisteredDate
```

In this particular use case, I don't see much benefit in use a database that is schema-less (mongodb), if your problem is scalability you can achieve it by purchasing better hardware (your site will be a success with millions of reviews, therefore you can afford it), or by performing proper data partitioning.

Comment: what if my site is social like users can follow each other and see each others review? I heared mySQL is not good at node relationships

Comment: neither mongodb is. You would need a graph database for such case. Once again you can kind of implement the graph with mysql, whereas would be cumbersome with mongodb. anyway, get your first million users first and afterwards hire  the database engineers. Don't over design.